# An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext - Servlet 3 with Async Support

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous, spring-security, servlet-3.0

Using Spring 3.2 with Async Support. The security context is lost once inside the anonymous `Callable` method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Callable<String> home(final Model model) {
    return new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            model.addAttribute("homeService", homeService.findId(1));
            return "home";
        }
    };
}
```

This is security decorator applied to a bean inside the `servlet-context.xml`

```
<beans:bean id="homeService" class="example.service.HomeServiceImpl" scope="request">
    <security:intercept-methods>
        <security:protect access="ROLE_USER" method="find*"/>
    </security:intercept-methods>
</beans:bean>
```

This is the error because a security context doesn't exist: 
`org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to [Spring Security 3.2.0 RC1](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) was the solution.

[This article](http://spring.io/blog/2012/12/17/spring-security-3-2-m1-highlights-servlet-3-api-support/) mentions Spring Security 3.2 being compatible with Servlet 3 Async Support.

> **Associating SecurityContext to Callable's**
>   More technically speaking,
>   Spring Security integrates with WebAsyncManager. The SecurityContext
>   that is used to process the Callable is the SecurityContext that
>   exists on the SecurityContextHolder at the time
>   startCallableProcessing is invoked.

Maven dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RC1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RC1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```